# Acceso denegado al crear fichero en java

Tags: java, archivo, texto

Cuando intento crear un fichero con el siguiente codigo:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejercicio2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ruta = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la ruta del fichero");
        String texto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el texto que quieres escribir en el fichero");
        escribirFichero(ruta, texto);

        mostrarFichero(ruta);

    }

    public static void escribirFichero(String nomFich, String texto) {
        try (FileWriter fich = new FileWriter(nomFich);) {

            // Escribimos el texto en el fichero
            fich.write(texto);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al escribir en el fichero " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void mostrarFichero(String nomFich) {

        System.out.println("El contenido de: " + nomFich + " es: ");
        // Leemos texto del fichero
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(nomFich)) {

            int caracter = fr.read();

            while (caracter != -1) {

                System.out.print((char) caracter);
                caracter = fr.read();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problema con la lectura/excritura en el fichero " + e);
        }

    }

}
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

Error al escribir en el fichero java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ESTUDIANTE\Documents\Ficheros (Acceso denegado)
El contenido de: C:\Users\ESTUDIANTE\Documents\Ficheros es:
Problema con la lectura/excritura en el fichero java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ESTUDIANTE\Documents\Ficheros (Acceso denegado)

Comment: Intenta reemplazar el \ por \\ y ve qué resultado te arroja.

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal es que no existe el archivo o no tienes permisos de escritura, escribe de esta forma la ruta:

```
C:/Users/ESTUDIANTE/Documents/Ficheros
```

o también :

```
C:\\Users\\ESTUDIANTE\\Documents\\Ficheros
```

pero la variable `ruta` de acuerdo a tu código ya debe tener el nombre del fichero, por lo tanto debes introducir la ruta y el nombre de tu archivo, por ejemplo:

```
C:/Users/ESTUDIANTE/Documents/Ficheros/texto.txt
```

Pero debes modificar tu método `escribirFichero()` ya que debe estar preparado para crear el archivo si es que no existe.

```
 public static void escribirFichero(String nomFich, String texto) {
    try { 
     File file = new File(nomFich); 
     if(!file.exists()){ //No existe
        file.createNewFile(); //Crea archivo.
     }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
           System.out.println("Error al escribir en el fichero " + ex);
    }
     
    try (FileWriter fich = new FileWriter(nomFich);) {

        // Escribimos el texto en el fichero
        fich.write(texto);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al escribir en el fichero " + e);
    }
}
```